# RecyclerView в NestedScrollView прокрутка "шалит"

Tags: recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Положил `RecyclerView` в `NestedScrollView`. При скролле вне `RecyclerView` все хорошо, а вот если скроллить по списку то отсутствует эффект "броска", тоесть при отпускании пальца скролл останавливается, а должен как бы докручивать.

Как можно вообще сделать `RecyclerView` не реагирующим на скролл, чтобы его кушал сразу `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать у `RecyclerView` метод

```
rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```